# Sort a list of sets

Tags: python

I have a list of sets on which I want to perform intersection.

Is there an efficient way to sort those sets by length, in order to optimize calculations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `key` argument of `sort` allows custom sort keys. Using `len` will do the trick:

```
l=<list_of_sets>
l.sort(key=len)
```

If you want the longest set first, use the `reverse` argument:

```
l.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
```

For example:

```
>>> l=[set((1,2,5,6,7)), set((1,2,3,4,5,6,7)), set((1,)), set((1,2,3))]
>>> l
[set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7]), set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), set([1]), set([1, 2, 3])]
>>> l.sort(key=len)
>>> l
[set([1]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7]), set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])]
>>> l.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
>>> l
[set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), set([1, 2, 5, 6, 7]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1])]
```

**Update:** Learned something today - lambda isn't necessary, because `len` is used without extra arguments. Therefore, `l.sort(lambda x:len(x))` is equivalent to `l.sort(key=len)`. Thanks, [Eugene Homyakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544621/eugene-homyakov)!

Comment: Lambda is not needed, you could just do `l.sort(key=len)`

Answer (score 7):

if L is the list of sets

```
sorted(L, key=len, reverse=True)
```

or to sort in place

```
L.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Small nitpick - PEP8 encourages small case in variable names. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: "Nits" are by definition small.

Comment: @Adam, single variable names in short pieces of code can make them easier to digest. PEP8 is really more about writing maintainable production code. lowercase `l` is often confused with the number `1`. There are even identical in some typefaces